# Is it possible to iterate all possible values in an interface property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to use all the possibilities in an interface property definition but could not find a way rather than manually typing them.

```js
// interface definition
interface Block {
    shape: 'square' | 'cycle' | 'triangle';
}
// I want to get a list of all shapes
const shapes: Block['shape'][] = ['square', 'cycle', 'triangle'];
```

I think it's a common problem, I just didn't get the exact keywords to search for the answer, please help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The type system is erased when TS is compiled to JS, so that JS would look like `const shapes = ['square', 'psycho', 'triangle']`. Those string names only appear once in the JS; you can't remove them.   My suggestion here would be to do the reverse of what you're asking; define `shapes` and then define `Block` in terms of it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQeGjw).  Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi @jcalz thanks for helping! If it's not possible to do that in TS, then I'll just let it go. Thanks for making the answer clear for me. In my case, I cannot do it reversely, since the type definition is generated from swagger api json, sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are only for compile time because typescript doesn't support it.

If you are okay with having it added during a compile time and you are using TypeScript >= 2.4.1, you can try the way proposed here.

Basically, you should add the ts-transformer-keys dependency, custom transformer, like a basic one and you'll be able to list the properties like this:

```
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';

interface Props {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
const keysOfProps = keys<Props>();

console.log(keysOfProps); // ['id', 'name', 'age']
```

Comment: "_because typescript doesn't support it_": I guess you mean something in the lines of "TS does not natively support iterating interface keys at runtime, since the interface is removed when transpiled"

Comment: It's different from what I'm asking actually. It's more like an enums in one property instead of an interface, e.g. `prop: 'A' | 'B' | 'C'` to be converted to `const p = ['A', 'B', 'C'];`